What’s the mood of “wish” in I wish sentences?
So, I have a task to identify the mood of bold verbs. As I understand “wish” in such sentences isn’t included in the Subjunctive mood? Pls help if I’m wrong
I wish you would pay attention. (wish – imperative; would pay attention – Present Subjunctive)
Nelly wished she were younger. (wished – Indicative; were - Present Subjunctive

"I wish" is not the imperative, though the sentence is in effect a command to pay attention. It's just an ordinary present tense.

As in your first example, it's usual these days to use "would" after "I wish" when expressing a command/request ("I wish you would stop doing that"). Since "would" doesn't have a distinct subjunctive form, you can use the regular form. Otherwise, you can use subjunctive for counterfactuals but it's not mandatory ("I wish I was younger" or "I wish I were younger").

Related (duplicate?): the meaning of "would" in "wish"-clauses. Note the difference there between I wish you would speak English and I wish you spoke English.

Does this answer your question? Are the sentences 'I wish my car would start' and 'I wish the lesson would end' correct?

English has dropped moods in favour of modal verbs or syntactic constructions. So verbs don't have mood, but you can talk about the mood of a clause.
The clause "I wish {...}" is indicative; it states a fact.  It is not imperative. The imperative is formed by omitting the subject and gives a command.
